# Issues with WebView Delegate

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I have some issues with this UIWebViewDelegate method.

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

**Issue:**
While changing any tab or clicking on any link, this method gets called automatically.
It was working fine for me also, but surprisingly it's not getting called since yesterday. I tried everything, but it's still not working. How can I resolve this?

Comment: did you check what changes you have made in the code since yesterday and find what happens on reverting those?

Answer (score 0):

Check u have done this:

```
 @interface yourViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
```

Also check add this line:

```
 yourWebView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Yes I have implemented those things

Answer (score 0):

IF you are making webView using xib then connect its delegate to file's owner, or if you are making webView through code then write

`myWebView.delegate = self;`

Comment: Already i have implemented that part of code
But still its not working
On start of web only its getting called once

Comment: IF you are using IB, the WebView's delegate needs to be connected to the `ViewController`. And the View Controller's WebView Variable needs to be connected to the `WebView`.